# Mercurial: Export last n revision into MQ

Tags: mercurial, workflow, mercurial-queue

is there an easy way to export last n commits into a new mq queue and strip the commits from the real repository?

I do often start out developing a new feature, later realising I did something wrong/would want to use MQ to fold patches.

I am currently doing:

1. Export last n commits as single patches
2. Strip last n commits
3. create new mq
4. import all patches in reverse order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simple (as long as there are no merges):

```
hg qimport -r base:tip
```

And voilà.

Comment: Your tip has served me well up until now. However I just hit the caveat you mentioned (as long as there are no merges). What can I do in this case?